# How to dynamically create a three-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I want to a array, for example:

```
[
    [
        [6,3,4],
        [5,2]
    ],
    [
        [8,5,7],
        [11,3]
    ]
]
```

And I just give you a simple example. In fact, the number of array of each dimensional will be changed with different conditions. And I don't want to use multiplication of list. I want to  create every element directly.

How to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: this is the same question asked at http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/70434 . more info can be found there.

Comment: You're using `list`s, not arrays.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Can you write the conditions? Because I'm assuming the logic determining them is what's going to drive the building of your arrays - it's pretty hard to answer without that info.

Comment: Take a look at the questions tagged both [`multi-dimensional-array` and `python`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multidimensional-array+python). It's got some useful things there. (Suggesting numpy, for example.)

Answer (score 6):

Use a mapping from your multi-dimensional index to your values.  Don't use a list of lists of lists.

```
array_3d = {
    (0,0,0): 6, (0,0,1): 3, (0,0,2): 4,
    (0,1,0): 5, (0,1,1): 2,
    (1,0,0): 8, (1,0,1): 5, (1,0,2): 7,
    (1,1,0): 11,(1,1,1): 3 
}
```

Now you don't have to worry about "pre-allocating" any size or or number of dimensions or anything.

Comment: And you can access it as `array_3d[1, 0, 2]`.

Answer (score 1):

I take dictionaries all the way for such cases:

```
def set_3dict(dict3,x,y,z,val):
  """Set values in a 3d dictionary"""
  if dict3.get(x) == None:
    dict3[x] = {y: {z: val}}
  elif dict3[x].get(y) == None:
    dict3[x][y] = {z: val}
  else:
    dict3[x][y][z] = val

d={}    
set_3dict(d,0,0,0,6)
set_3dict(d,0,0,1,3) 
set_3dict(d,0,0,2,4)
...
```

In anology I have a getter

```
def get_3dict(dict3, x, y, z, preset=None):
  """Read values from 3d dictionary"""
  if dict3.get(x, preset) == preset:
    return preset
  elif dict3[x].get(y, preset) == preset:
    return preset
  elif dict3[x][y].get(z, preset) == preset:
    return preset
  else: return dict3[x][y].get(z)

>>> get3_dict(d,0,0,0)
 6
>>> d[0][0][0]
 6
>>> get3_dict(d,-1,-1,-1)
 None
>>> d[-1][-1][-1]
 KeyError: -1
```

In my opinion the advantage lies in iterating over the field being quite simple:

```
for x in d.keys():
  for y in d[x].keys():
    for z in d[x][y].keys():
      print d[x][y][z]
```

Answer (score -2):

Um, pretty much the way you'd think. In Python they're called lists, not arrays, but you just have a triple-nested list, like,

```
threeDList = [[[]]]
```

and then you use three indices to identify elements, like

```
threeDList[0][0].append(1)
threeDList[0][0].append(2)
#threeDList == [[[1,2]]]
threeDList[0][0][1] = 3
#threeDList == [[[1,3]]]
```

You just have to be careful that every index you use refers to a place in the list that already exists (i.e. threeDList[0][0][2] or threeDList[0][1] or threeDList[1] does not exist in this example), and when possible, just use comprehensions or for loops to manipulate the elements of the list.

Hope this helps!

Comment: -1: he knows about this way of doing it but it doesn't fit his constraints; "In fact, the number of array of each dimensional will be changed with different conditions."

Comment: Yes, that's why I told him how to "manipulate every element directly".

Comment: His point is that it isn't a three-dimensional array insofar as no constraints are forced in it. You could have `threeDList[0][0]` containing five elements, `threeDList[0][1]` containing seventeen, `threeDList[4]` containing none; it's not a definition of a cubic array.

Comment: Leastways, I *think* that's what his point is... the more I read it the more I'm just generally confused.

Comment: Yep. And as I probably didn't explain well enough, the mutability of Python lists (they're not like C or Java arrays) makes that very easy to do.